# Screen Overflowed by some pixels in Flutter app even after use text overflow

Tags: flutter

In my flutter app, I use **TextOverflow.clip** to wrap text. But it shows me screen overflowed by some pixel.
Here is my Code example screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please copy the code directly when asking questions. Avoid posting pictures of your code.

Comment: The problem can be fixed by wrapping the Column widget inside an Expanded widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Row(
  children: [
    SizedBox(
      //...
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        //...
      ),
      //...
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          //...
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```